# Rest Service method mapping [Java Spring]

Tags: java, spring, rest, optimization, controller

This is my first try at writting service from scratch. I'm using RestController and Java Spring to create a service which generates pdf based on parameters which are passed when calling the service. Service is called with one parameter, but can be called with two different variables (one is registry number and the other is identificator) and depending on which one of those two is passed, service generates the same JSON but different service is called in background of my program (one call works with IDN and one works with regNum).

So far I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generatePdf/{idn}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public String generatePdf(@PathVariable String idn) {
    //logic
}
```

My question is this. What is the best solution for this problem? 
Do I make separate method with different name and mapping?
Should I create a flag which checks which type od data is sent? Or, something third, feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to create separate method instead of adding the additional flag:

- API will be more readable and understandable, eg: GET /pdfByIdn/{idn} and GET /pdfByRN/{rn}
- Easy to add additional cases, without modification of existing methods
- Its make more sense to use separate service classes to different approaches to generate PDF's

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generatePdf/{idn}/{rgn}", method = 
RequestMethod.GET, 
produces = "application/pdf")
public String generatePdf(@PathVariable(required = false) String idn, 
@PathVariable(required = false) String rgn) 
{
if(idn.equals(null){
//logic
}else {
//logic
}
}
```

Comment: But this method you wrote is called with 2 parameters and I need a call with one

Comment: use @PathVariable(required = false)